# Major issues after updating IE10

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10, local-storage

When I first upgraded to IE10's final Preview on Windows 7, I immediately started getting the following error whenever a script tries to access `localStorage`:

> SCRIPT3: The system cannot find the path specified.

Interestingly, this error can't be `try..catch`ed. But that's beside the point. I "fixed" the problem simply by turning off Protected Mode.

But now I've updated to the actual release of IE10, and the error's back. Toggling Protected Mode isn't working! I can't access half my own sites, nor can I log in on StackExchange sites! I'm having to use Chrome instead to post this!

Does anyone know what could cause this error and how to fix it? I really need help with this as work cannot continue without that browser to test in!

(Microsoft's support are no use - first the system tells me they have higher-than-normal call volume, then they tell me they're closed. HUH?)

Comment: Have you moved or remapped any of your User directories (eg AppData)?

Comment: Nope. Literally the only thing I did between it working perfectly and it crashing horribly was update it - I even went so far as to uncheck all the Windows updates, *only* updating IE. I thought updates were supposed to **fix** bugs :p

Comment: So you went from IE9 to IE10 Platform Preview to IE 10 Final, right? If it's possible, can you try uninstalling IE10, reverting to IE9, then upgrading directly to IE10 Final?

Comment: That is correct. I'm not entirely sure how to downgrade IE, it's never something I've even considered! Could you explain how to do that for me?

Comment: Just posting an update, I have found instructions and successfully downgraded to IE9. `localStorage` is now working again. I will now attempt to re-upgrade to IE10.

Comment: @Karan Unfortunately, as soon as I upgraded to IE10 again, the error came right back.

Comment: Since I've not attempted the upgrade to IE10 myself yet, I'm not sure whether this is a general issue or something specific to your system. All I can suggest is a browser reset (`Internet Options / Advanced tab`), but since it's anyway a fresh install guess that's redundant. Still, perhaps you can try it just for fun?

Comment: @Karan It worked! Feel free to post that as an answer and I will gladly Accept it.

Comment: That's great, glad it worked! Now I feel a bit more confident about upgrading to IE10 myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments section above, a corrupt file or incorrect setting in IE might have been responsible for the issue. A browser reset (via the `Internet Options / Advanced tab`) solved the problem.

Comment: I think I rebooted my computer more times in the last two hours than in the last six months combined XD

Answer (score 2):

We also fell victim to this problem because we ran CCleaner on the machine.

To solve it, go into:

Internet Options -> Browsing History -> Delete:

Make sure to check all options except the very first one (Preserve Favorite website data).

We were able to fix, then reproduce this issue by using CCleaner again, then fix again.

Go to this site for more information: http://grekai.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/localstorage-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/